# interest rate java confusion with private static doubles

Tags: java

alright so i have already made a working compound interest rate program. but now for this program i have to re write the program using more methods. using

```
private static double FVCALC(..)
```

and

```
private static double validate(........)
```

i dont quite understand how i need to do this. the current code i have only lets me input the 3 values of interest rate and it stops. is it because of the `private` mehtods? im not sure what to do and i have searched for 3 days now.

bottom line is. my code is not working the way i want it to.

```
public class interest_rate 
{

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            double i;
            double n;
            double FVCalc;
            double PV;
            System.out.print("please enter value for n (years): ");
            n = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("please enter interest rate: ");
            i=input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("please enter Present Value: ");
            PV = input.nextDouble();        


    }
    private static double validate (double upLimit, double lowLimit, double PV)
    {

        upLimit=100000.00;
        lowLimit=0.00;
        while(PV>upLimit|| PV<lowLimit)
        {
            System.out.print("please enter value between "+upLimit+" and "+lowLimit);
            System.out.print("please enter PV");
            PV=input.nextDouble();
        }



        return PV;


    }




    private static double FVCalc(double PV, double i, double n, double FV)
    {


        FV = PV*Math.pow(1+(i/100), n);

        return(FV);
    }

}
```

Comment: the program needs to validate PV between 0-100,000

Comment: also i am a noob at this

Comment: Please edit your post instead of adding comments. Also, don't give unnecessary information, solely the problem

Comment: Another thing: please try to format your code as best as possible. You want us to help; so you please spend some time making your code as readable as possible!

Comment: thanks for all the help ill make sure to make it pretty. ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Interestingly enough, your way of coding ... did hide the problem that is actually pretty obvious: Java does "pass by value". And therefore, when you use some PV or FV as argument to a method call ... the caller does **not** see when the called method changes its parameters!

Comment: You never call the two methods you wrote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to **call** the methods in main.

Secondly, you cant pass in `PV`, then reassign it and expect the value to update.

For example..

```
private static double validate (double upLimit, double lowLimit, double PV)
```

You need to call this in main like so

```
PV = 0.0; // some double value 
double validated = validate(0,100000); // return the value, don't pass it in
```

And remove these lines in that method because overriding parameters is typically bad.

```
upLimit=100000.00;
lowLimit=0.00;
```

Next, add a field for your values that you want to use throughout the class.

```
public class InterestRate 
{

    static double pv , fvCalc;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
```

And remove these lines in main and use those two class variables instead

```
double FVCalc;
double PV;
```

Additionally, I don't see a reason to store fvCalc as a variable. You can just calculate it

```
private static double fvCalc(double pV, double i, double n)
{
    return pV*Math.pow(1+(i/100), n);   
}
```

Comment: thank you. what you have told me jump started my brain again.

Answer (score 0):

i believe i have figured it out. and i made it pretty. excuse the notes. i wanted to keep them there to see what i did wrong. thanks all.

```
public class interest_rate 
{
    static double pV , fvCalc, i, n;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double validated;
        double calculated;
        double i;
        double n;
        //double fV; 
        //double pV1;
        System.out.print("please enter value for n (years): ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("please enter interest rate: ");
        i=input.nextDouble();
        validated = validate(0,100000); 
        System.out.println("pV is validated and equal to: "+validated);
        calculated= fvCalc(validated,i,n);
        System.out.println("your calulation for interest is: "+calculated);
    }
    private static double validate(double upLimit, double lowLimit) {
    double pV;
    System.out.print("please enter pV");
    pV=input.nextDouble();
    while(pV<upLimit|| pV>lowLimit)
    {
        System.out.print("please enter value between "+upLimit+" and "+lowLimit);
        System.out.println("please enter pV");
        pV=input.nextDouble();
    }
    return pV;
    }
    private static double fvCalc(double pV, double i, double n)
    {
        double fV;
        fV=pV*Math.pow(1+(i/100), n);   
        return fV;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks okay, except be careful with `double i;` in the main method because it is shadowing the class variable of the same name

Comment: agreed ill change that. thanks